# How to calculate approximate historical price of options?

Tags: option-pricing

Assuming that I have access to the historical daily closing price, it is possible to approximately calculate the daily price of an option? I understand that one pricing model is the Black-Scholes model. However this requires implied volatility (IV) to get an accurate result. As I understand it, IV cannot be calculated from historical stock prices.

Comment: Hi, could you please clarify which prices you have at hand and which prices you want to assess - and at which frequency?

Comment: Hi @Kermittfrog, I am able to get the date, daily open, daily high, daily low, daily close, daily volume of the equity. I would like to also estimate via a calculate the daily end price of an option.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Well, unfortunately, that is not possible without information on the implied volatility. Of course there exist corner cases where the option is extremely deep in the money or deep out of the money, but that will most probably not be of help. You do need values for the underlying (which you have) *and* a time series of implied volatilities, sorry.